# Lightweight linux OS for hadoop installation

Tags: linux, linux-distributions

Can anybody tell which is the best linux lightweight Os for hadoop installation.
I want to install hadoop only for performing lab practicals. As my machine (2gb ram , intel centrino duo processor, 500gb) is old that's why i'm asking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best bet is the [Ubuntu minimal ISO](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) and from there install only the required packages without a graphical interface or a very lightweight one if you absolutely need an interface. Considering you only have 2GB of ram even doing some browsing would be limited on this machine so try to avoid having a GUI.

By having a lightweight Ubuntu, installing Hadoop will not be difficult to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Bogdan. Lubuntu can be a good option too. 512MB RAM should be good enough. Also issue this command "sudo apt-get --purge autoremove lxde" if you want to strip down Lubuntu's GUI and dont need any file browser.